# SQL: Trying to SELECT COUNT one column and at the same time show another column

Tags: sql

For homework I need to search the IMDb database and find in what year the most documentaries came out. So I got this query:

```
SELECT  START_YEAR, COUNT(*)
FROM MOVIE
WHERE GENRE = 'Documentary'
GROUP BY START_YEAR
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This is the result from the query:

```
START_YEAR  | COUNT
____________|_________
2017        | 52
2018        | 43
2015        | 39
...         | ...
```

But I need the table to show this:

```
GENRE      |  START_YEAR  |  COUNT
___________|______________|_________
Documentary| 2017         | 52
Documentary| 2018         | 43
Documentary| 2015         | 39
...        | ...          | ...
```

I keep getting an error when I add something to the SELECT-clause. I don't know what to do, I'm a beginner in SQL and everything in the query above is all I know about SQL lol
Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 1):

Also add it to the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT GENRE, START_YEAR, COUNT(*)
FROM MOVIE
WHERE GENRE = 'Documentary'
GROUP BY GENRE, START_YEAR
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Or use a constant:

```
SELECT 'Documentary' as GENRE, START_YEAR, COUNT(*)
FROM MOVIE
WHERE GENRE = 'Documentary'
GROUP BY START_YEAR
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Or use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT MAX(GENRE) as GENRE, START_YEAR, COUNT(*)
FROM MOVIE
WHERE GENRE = 'Documentary'
GROUP BY START_YEAR
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```